# Where is the brew app stored in a Mac?

Tags: java, macos

I'm trying to install a package using Brew, via my Java app (ie no terminal is used).

While my install command works as expected in the terminal, it doesn't work on my Java app. The error is `error=2, No such file or directory`, so I'm guessing the keyword `brew` is not recognized.

I'm running my command like this from Java: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("brew install somepackage")`.

Now I'm trying to find the path to brew so that I could try this: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec({"/some/path/to/brew", "install somepackage"})`.

My problem is that I don't know where brew is stored in my mac.

Anyone knows?

Thanks

Comment: Side note: this is really more of an "environment" question; actually it has nothing to do with neither programming nor java. superuser.com would be a better place to task such questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can run
`which brew`
on your command line to see the path to your brew binary.
It defaults to `/usr/local/bin/brew`.

The reason that the call from java does not work is probably caused by the unchanged PATH variable within java, that you changed in your ~/.bash_profile to include /usr/local/bin

Comment: Thanks, I think this worked. I called the brew command from the path. Funnily enough, my bash_profile doesn't have a path to brew. Maybe it's referenced in some other profile?

Comment: please refer to your favorite search engine or superuser.com to see how your environment variables can be changed